# How do I drop rows where ticker AXP has missing values for Adj Close (i.e., rows where Adj Close is NaN)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, drop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThnfY.png)

df_wide.dropna(subset=['Adj Close'])

I got ^ formula but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

df_wide[~df_wide[“Adj Close”].isna()], should do the trick this is basically saying df_wide where close is not blank. The tilde ~ means not.